# Cake site not finding images nor CSS files after moving it to my localhost?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using cake1.3.5

I recently moved a live working site into my localhost:

[image]

I set config.php to my local database but when I enter the site, I see this:

[image]

Is it there any additional step I am missing (concerning the file path or something)?

Comment: Bellow answer did not work in my condition, so can you please suggest me something more to solve my issue. I am also having the same issue. @alexchenco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cake directs all its call to webroot folder (by default called URL rewriting). This is achieved via .htaccess file in the document root, which MUST have (for URL rewriting to work)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess file inside the webroot folder should contain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   // this line traps requests for directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   // this line traps requests for file names
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The two lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` & `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` are essential in parsing requests for directories and file names.

The line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]` deals with anything which is not a file or directory.

1. Check if mod_rewrite is enabled or not.
2. There must be two .htaccess file, one in the root folder and other one in the webroot folder. The contents of both these .htaccess files must be different.

You may wanna check out [URL rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)

You can [turn off URL rewriting from Core Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration-baseurl)

Answer (score 0):

having gone through the same scenario, it turns out that the localhost did not recognise  short style tags are only available when they are enabled in php.ini configuration file on servers.

When I changed the tags to  all the pages appeared normally.

Comment: How to enable short style tag in php.ini @Andy